# When to close connection to an oracle db from Asp.net

Tags: android, asp.net, database, oracle, database-connection

I'm using a asp.net application to retrive my data from oracle db, & return them as json to use them in my android application.

I was wondering if I have to open , close my connection to the db everytime I do a request or if it's better to open my connection once and keep it opened because the application that I'm programming will be Opened for like 24h/7d .

I've read something about connection pool, but it's a little bit confusing me,

because I don't know if the connection pool will be used as I use a mobile application to ask my asp.net application.

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: Even If you want your server up and running do close your connections after your work done. If you keep your connection open and multiple user are connected to your server it may lead to connection pool full exception.

Comment: thanks a lot I see now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 options.

1. Open and and close the database on every request.
2. Open the database on Initialize, close it on `Page_UnLoad` or on `OnError`
3. Open the database for ever, close it on recycle.

We start with the (1), we then optimize if we can with (2), and we avoid the (3).

Why we avoid the 3d option, because we probably may end with conflicts on call if we have many pools, or many threads, and also probably left with many open connections end up with out any free other to use.

We need the (1) by default because we always need some extra call for ask something from the database -

And we optimize with (2) because at page render, we need usually more than one database call - one shared open connection only for one call can increase the speed at little bit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your service are stateless. Then the connections are automatically terminated after every request and everything that is still in memory is cleared (as long it is not static). 
But nevertheless it would be better if you wrapped everything you do against the database with usings. This will automatically close all connections and clear everything. e.g. =>

```
using (System.Data.IDbConnection con = DBFactory.CreateDbConnection(Session))
{
    using (System.Data.IDbCommand cmd = DBFactory.CreateDbCommand(con))
    {
```

You can even do this when you have multiple queries. If you want to connect them , you have to do it with a transaction. A transaction keeps the connection open even if you close it.
You don't have to worry about the speed, because .Net is running a connection pooling in the background and doesn't really close the connections.

I hope that helps!